# Difference between Windows SDK's

Tags: .net

I have got work to do on some old script/batch file. It is referring signing exe from microsoft SDK directory. I have current installation of SDK upto V6.0A and script refers to V7.0A. I installed SDK for framework 3.5 and 4 they are having versions as V7.0 and V7.1.

Now which SDK I should install to get V7.0A?

Comment: More info on the versions in the wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v7.0a and v7.0 are technically equal. Version v7.0a is installed with visual studio 2010. Version v7.0 comes with the normal installation .NET Framework 3.5 SP 1.

EDIT: 
see [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK) from Erno de Weerd, they even share the same build number.

Comment: You don't have VS 2010 installed and hence there is no v7.0a. you can modify the script to force it to refer to v7.0 and you are done.